# React Native Axios couldn't catch error from Network Request Failed

Tags: android, react-native, axios

So, I have a function to call my API when logging in in my react native app. Somehow right now the server has an error when I try to call the API: `connect ECONNREFUSED 103.129.220.210:443`.

I thought this error should be caught in my try-catch block program or .then and .catch block program. However, it just pops warning in my log and doesn't go to my catch block or anything. Here is my login fucntion code:

```
logIn: (email, password) => {
        dispatch({type: 'LOADING'})
        try {
          console.log("API call in login function")
          axios.post('https://dev.akademis.id/api/user/login', {
            "email": email,
            "password": password
          })
            .then(async res => {
              const userToken = String(res.data.data.id)
              if (res.data.data.ptn && res.data.data.jurusan) dispatch({type: 'PROFILE SET'})

              try {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', userToken)
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('userPass', password)
              } catch (e) {
                console.log("Error dari async storage: ")
                console.error(e)
                dispatch({type: 'STOP LOADING'})

                throw e
              }

              dispatch({type: 'LOGIN', token: userToken, password: password})
            })
            .catch(err => {
              Alert.alert("Error", err.response.data.message)
              console.log(err.response.data.message)
              dispatch({type: 'STOP LOADING'})

              throw(err)
              // Email & pass required, using @, and ., pass minimum 8 chars
            })
        } catch (e) {
          Alert.alert("Server dalam maintainance", "Kami meminta maaf atas ketidaknyamanan ini")
          console.log(e.response)
          dispatch({type: 'STOP LOADING'})
        }
      }
```

Here is my error in log:

```
API call in login function
[Tue Sep 29 2020 08:52:54.884]  WARN     Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Network request failed
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:26065:33
_callTimer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30563:17
callTimers@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30771:19
__callFunction@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2776:36
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2508:31
__guard@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2730:15
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2507:21
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
``
```

Comment: Which library are you using? https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios or https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-axios?

Comment: I'm using the react-native-axios

Comment: Try to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios - react-native-axios is not up-to-date, last published 4 years ago. I had the same problem, switching to npmjs.com/package/axios solved the problem